# When does the V8 GC trigger its first minor gc cycle (scavenge)?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, v8

I'm trying to understand how this simple code that allocates one megabyte:

```
var BYTES_IN_MB = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB = 1024KB = 1024(KB/MB)*1024(B/KB)
var BYTES_IN_SMI = 4;
var NUM_SMIS_IN_MB = BYTES_IN_MB/BYTES_IN_SMI;

var y = [];
function allocateMB() {
  for(var i = 0; i < NUM_SMIS_IN_MB; i++) {
    y.push(i);
  }
}

allocateMB();
```

Results in 4 minor gc cycles (scavenges). As you can see, we explicitly set the size of the new space to one megabyte. The expected result was to see one scavenge, but I don't understand why we see four instead.

```
➜  ~  d8
V8 version 4.5.103.35 [console: readline]
➜  ~  d8 --trace_gc --trace_gc_verbose  --min_semi_space_size=1 --max_semi_space_size=1 --target_semi_space_size=1 --semi_space_growth_factor=0 allocateMB.js
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600]        6 ms: Scavenge 1.7 (36.9) -> 1.2 (36.9) MB, 0.3 / 0 ms [allocation failure].
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Memory allocator,   used:  37752 KB, available: 1461384 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] New space,          used:    281 KB, available:    726 KB, committed:   2015 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Old space,          used:    674 KB, available:      0 KB, committed:    794 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Code space,         used:    194 KB, available:      0 KB, committed:    261 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Map space,          used:     34 KB, available:      0 KB, committed:     59 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Large object space, used:      0 KB, available: 1460343 KB, committed:      0 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] All spaces,         used:   1185 KB, available: 1461069 KB, committed:   3130 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] External memory reported:      0 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Total time spent in GC  : 0.3 ms
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600]        7 ms: Scavenge 1.5 (36.9) -> 1.3 (36.9) MB, 0.4 / 0 ms [allocation failure].
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Memory allocator,   used:  37752 KB, available: 1461384 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] New space,          used:    397 KB, available:    610 KB, committed:   2015 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Old space,          used:    691 KB, available:      0 KB, committed:    794 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Code space,         used:    194 KB, available:      0 KB, committed:    261 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Map space,          used:     34 KB, available:      0 KB, committed:     59 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Large object space, used:      0 KB, available: 1460343 KB, committed:      0 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] All spaces,         used:   1317 KB, available: 1460954 KB, committed:   3130 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] External memory reported:      0 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Total time spent in GC  : 0.7 ms
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600]        8 ms: Scavenge 1.9 (36.9) -> 1.5 (36.9) MB, 0.2 / 0 ms [allocation failure].
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Memory allocator,   used:  37752 KB, available: 1461384 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] New space,          used:    596 KB, available:    411 KB, committed:   2015 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Old space,          used:    691 KB, available:      0 KB, committed:    794 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Code space,         used:    194 KB, available:      0 KB, committed:    261 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Map space,          used:     34 KB, available:      0 KB, committed:     59 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Large object space, used:      0 KB, available: 1460343 KB, committed:      0 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] All spaces,         used:   1516 KB, available: 1460755 KB, committed:   3130 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] External memory reported:      0 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Total time spent in GC  : 0.9 ms
[2853] Limited new space size due to high promotion rate: 1 MB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600]        8 ms: Scavenge 1.5 (36.9) -> 1.5 (37.9) MB, 0.7 / 0 ms [allocation failure].
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Memory allocator,   used:  38776 KB, available: 1460360 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] New space,          used:      0 KB, available:   1007 KB, committed:   2015 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Old space,          used:   1287 KB, available:    102 KB, committed:   1801 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Code space,         used:    194 KB, available:      0 KB, committed:    261 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Map space,          used:     34 KB, available:      0 KB, committed:     59 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Large object space, used:      0 KB, available: 1459319 KB, committed:      0 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] All spaces,         used:   1516 KB, available: 1460430 KB, committed:   4138 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] External memory reported:      0 KB
[2853:0x7fa1fa012600] Total time spent in GC  : 1.6 ms
```

Comment: Well, what happens if you insert more/less numbers to the array (how many scavenges? is it the number you would expect?) And for answering the question I'd recommend setting a breakpoint and trying to grok what's triggering the scavenges by reading stack trace

Comment: Why do you expect to see one scavenge?

Comment: I should only see one (two at most) because I am only allocating one MB and that's the size of the new-space (set via --min_semi_space_size=1 --max_semi_space_size=1 --target_semi_space_size=1 flags). A scavenge is triggered when the new-space gets full. Four scavenges implies that the new-space was full four times! but I only allocated one MB.

Comment: For some reason I cannot reproduce. Which version of v8 do you have?

Comment: @VladislavIvanishin Can you pastebin your output? I'm using version 4.5.103.35. What's your version?

Comment: My output is empty! The shell says "V8 version 4.8.0 (candidate)". [The git commit is 30236c0.]

Comment: Upd: reproduced with 4.6.1

Comment: @VladislavIvanishin Ok good. Glad it's at least reproducible

Comment: 1MB is 976KB..... that depends on what you use.

Comment: Your `allocateMB()` does not even necessarily allocate a megabyte. Did you study the grow mechanism of the array? Can its size ever be exactly one megabyte?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the new space uses a [semi-space allocation strategy](http://v8project.blogspot.se/2015/08/getting-garbage-collection-for-free.html) (see under "Deep Dive..."), so it's not necessarily an exact 1MB limit. In fact, it seems like at most [80%](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/heap/scavenge-job.cc#L17) of the new space is allowed to be filled.

There is also a mechanism for ensuring quick scavenges by changing the allocation limit (see line 55 in the 80% link). So the GC behavior is not as straightforward as it seems, but reading the V8 source code and comments gives good hints.

Answer (score 1):

"allocateMb" shows an incomplete understanding of array size. An array size starts with 4 and the size is grown with `x1.5 + 16` every time it needs to be resized. So you actually resize the array like this:

```
4      (garbage so far: 4 * 4 + 1 * 2 * 4 =       24 bytes [48 in 64-bit])
22     (garbage so far: 26 * 4 + 2 * 2 * 4 =      120 bytes [240 in 64-bit])
49     (garbage so far: 75 * 4 + 3 * 2 * 4 =      324 bytes [648 in 64-bit])
89     (garbage so far: 164 * 4 + 4 * 2 * 4 =     688 bytes [1376 in 64-bit])
149    (garbage so far: 313 * 4 + 5 * 2 * 4 =     1292 bytes [2584 in 64-bit])
239    (garbage so far: 552 * 4 + 6 * 2 * 4 =     2256 bytes [4512 in 64-bit])
374    (garbage so far: 926 * 4 + 7 * 2 * 4 =     3760 bytes [7520 in 64-bit])
577    (garbage so far: 1503 * 4 + 8 * 2 * 4 =    6076 bytes [12152 in 64-bit])
881    (garbage so far: 2384 * 4 + 9 * 2 * 4 =    9608 bytes [19216 in 64-bit])
1337   (garbage so far: 3721 * 4 + 10 * 2 * 4 =   14964 bytes [29928 in 64-bit])
2021   (garbage so far: 5742 * 4 + 11 * 2 * 4 =   23056 bytes [46112 in 64-bit])
3047   (garbage so far: 8789 * 4 + 12 * 2 * 4 =   35252 bytes [70504 in 64-bit])
4586   (garbage so far: 13375 * 4 + 13 * 2 * 4 =  53604 bytes [107208 in 64-bit])
6895   (garbage so far: 20270 * 4 + 14 * 2 * 4 =  81192 bytes [162384 in 64-bit])
10358  (garbage so far: 30628 * 4 + 15 * 2 * 4 =  122632 bytes [245264 in 64-bit])
15553  (garbage so far: 46181 * 4 + 16 * 2 * 4 =  184852 bytes [369704 in 64-bit])
23345  (garbage so far: 69526 * 4 + 17 * 2 * 4 =  278240 bytes [556480 in 64-bit])
35033  (garbage so far: 104559 * 4 + 18 * 2 * 4 = 418380 bytes [836760 in 64-bit])
52565  (garbage so far: 157124 * 4 + 19 * 2 * 4 = 628648 bytes [1257296 in 64-bit])
78863  (garbage so far: 235987 * 4 + 20 * 2 * 4 = 944108 bytes [1888216 in 64-bit])
118310 (garbage so far: 354297 * 4 + 21 * 2 * 4 = 1417356 bytes [2834712 in 64-bit])
177481 (garbage so far: 531778 * 4 + 22 * 2 * 4 = 2127288 bytes [4254576 in 64-bit])
266237 (not garbage)
```

So before the sufficient size `266237` is reached, that's `FixedArray` garbage worth of `531778 * 4 + 22 * 2 * 4 =` `2127288` bytes or `4254576` bytes in 64-bit. Also, the last garbage array of `177481` cannot be even allocated in new space because it takes 1419864 bytes in 64-bit.

For smaller arrays up to 100k items in size you can skip the wasteful resizing by doing `new Array(size)`.

A trick I use with unknown array size is giving an approximation and then resetting the length:

```
var myArray = new Array(1024)
myArray.length = 0;
// Can now use .push without having to resize the backing array
```